# WordPress site help me

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am designing a WordPress site
...
I have a contact with us in the menu section of the WordPress website, Imam, now that I want to design, I have another contact with us, an additional one. How can I completely hide an additional contact with us? I will let you see the photo I want now.

I marked in front of the desired photo with red color (which I want to hide).

I am new to WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

First : You can add css code in WordPress theme editor

```
.your ClassName {display : none;}
```

maybe i think it is very simple for you

Comment: No, it wasn't... I fixed it myself.. Thank you for answering again